# Which one is more likely to happen:$10$ tosses with $5$ head up and $100$ tosses with $50$ head up?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we have a fair coin is tossed multiple times, which one is more likely to happen:
$10$ tosses with $5$ head up or $100$ tosses with $50$ head up.

So the question translates mathematically into comparing the following two numbers $${10\choose 5} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{10}}\quad\text{and}\quad{100\choose 50} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{100}}.$$

I used computer and knew the former one is (much) larger. So I am wondering if there is a mathematical way which we can show the result by hand? Thanks!

Comment: You could use Stirling's approximation for the factorials in $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Comment: You might use the Normal distribution to find an approximate result for the second of the two outcomes.

Comment: Intuitively, you could think of getting 5 heads out of 10 flips as getting between (45 and 55) heads out of 100 flips.  In addition, since there are a lot more options for 100 flips and probabilities add to 1, the individual probabilities need to be much smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some $n$, there's

$${2n\choose n} \cdot 2^{-2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!2^{2n}}$$ chance of getting $n$ heads out of $2n$ flips.

For $n+1$, we have

$${2n+2\choose n+1} \cdot 2^{-(2n+2)}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!2^{2n+2}}$$

Divide the second result by the first:

$$=\frac{(2n+2)!n!n!2^{2n}}{(2n)!(n+1)!(n+1)!2^{2n+2}}=\frac{(2n+1)(2(n+1))}{4(n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$

is the ratio of the chance of flipping $n+1$ heads out of $2n+2$ coins to the chance of flipping $n$ heads out of $2n$ coins, i.e. the amount by which your probability of half heads will change if you add another two flips to the mix. Since it's under $1$, by induction, it will always shrink, and so the probability of half heads is always larger with fewer coins.

Check by plugging in $n=1$ for one heads out of two flips compared to $n=2$ for two heads out of four flips, and we have $\frac{3}{4}=\frac{0.375}{0.5}$, which looks right to me for those first two cases.

---

Now that I look at it again, I guess you can use that result to simply say

$$P(n\text{ heads in }2n\text{ flips})=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\cdots (5)(3)(1)}{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\cdots (4)(2)}.$$

So yeah, that's another way to conclude $P$ must go down as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to demonstrate that $$p_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\frac1{2^{2n}}$$
is decreasing function of $n$. In this answer a practical way to estimate the value of the coefficient will be shown.

For large $n$ we can compute the probability using the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) as follows:
$$
p_n\approx 
\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}}{2\pi n\left(\frac{n}e\right)^{2n}}\frac1{4^n}=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$

This means that for large $n$ and $k$, the ratio of probabilities is:
$$
\frac{p_n}{p_k}\approx\sqrt{\frac kn}.
$$

Somewhat surprisingly it works well already in your example:
$$
\left(\frac{p_{5}}{p_{50}}\right)^2\approx 9.56076.
$$